# Rscript does not recognize setGeneric function

Tags: r, batch-file, rscript

I am trying to convert an R script into something that a client can run in batch mode. My code uses generic functions and one snippet which is near the beginning goes like:

```
setGeneric("testInput", function(inputData, params = list())
    standardGeneric("testInput"))
```

I've been using **R CMD BATCH** and it works fine. However I couldn't find an easy way to make my script print the output on the console, so based on that (and suggestion that Rscript.exe is the "proper" way to run R batch files) I decided to switch to **Rscript**. However when running the very same .R file with Rscript I get the following:

```
Error: could not find function "setGeneric"
Execution halted
```

I know there is probably a trivial reason behind this but I just cannot figure it out. Can someone please point me to where the mistake is?
Any suggestions?

Comment: add `require(methods)` at the begining of your script

Comment: @dickoa, +1. Lest this question go officially 'unanswered', would you mind converting your comment to an answer?

Comment: @gung You're right, I converted my comment to an answer...thanks

Answer (score 3):

`setGeneric` is part of the `methods` package which is usually loaded when you start R in an interactive session but not in non interactive session using `Rscript` or `littler`.

So you need to add a `require(methods)` before calling `setGeneric` in your script.

For example, this code will not work

```
Rscript -e "setGeneric('mean', function(x) standardGeneric('mean'))"
Error: could not find function "setGeneric"
Execution halted
```

But this one will work

```
Rscript -e "require(methods);setGeneric('mean', function(x) standardGeneric('mean'))"
Loading required package: methods
[1] "mean"
```